# Upload cross-sell products using CSV without extensions

Tags: magento

How can I upload cross-sell products using a CSV file in magento? I already tried using some extensions, but is there any default setting in magento that does it? I want to avoid using extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with **MAGMI**. Please check this link http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Cross/Upsell_Importer

You will need a simple csv having column names

sku and us_skus and there values as "00002","00001,00000"

Comment: Thank You for your solution.